# MySQL collation error with non english characters

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, collation

I have problem with showing utf8_general_ci characters. I've set all my tables and columns to utf8 but all non-english alphabet characters dont show (they do but encrypted like this Å¡ÄÄ‡Å¾Ä‘). Also signs like ' + etc. don't show up. I am running my website on Bluehost.

What is confusing me, is that I use AJAX on my website. When I call AJAX files characters show normaly, but when loaded in non-ajax pages I have an error, I told you about.

Comment: can you see the correct characters in the database tables?

Comment: what is the field data type?

Comment: Are you properly escaping your queries or using prepared PDO statements?

Comment: Is your connection/query setting set to utf-8? And web page?  Use something like `mysqli_query($this->_db,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");` inside your connection class or in your function.

Comment: Does the data look good in PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: I have connection query like this

$link = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_set_charset('utf8_general_ci',$link);

Comment: Thank you guys solved the problem! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you don't see the problem with Ajax, is because javascript encoding is UTF-8. This is not the case with PHP, so you should add this to your php.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to know where a charset is used:

- the data (set with `collation/charset` in MySQL)
- the webpage (use your file editor, switch encoding) (in this case the page contents are not relevant I think)
- the page as your browser requests it (`Content-Type:` header + `<meta>`-tag)
- the MySQL connection (let `SET NAMES 'utf8';` be your first query)
- Under which encoding you put the data into the database: Only put UTF-8 encoded data into your UTF-8 column.

I think that you have wrong encoded data in a correct encoded field, so make sure your data is even UTF-8 before you put it into the database, e.g the page where your form is etc.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your browser interprets it as UTF-8. Do this with the help of the meta-tags in HTML.

Example:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
```